# MongoDB - mongod "Address already in use" error

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB and cannot understand how to fix this:

tried different things I saw on mongodb.com, including stack overflow, but still receive the same "Address already in use" error message. the mongo shell works fine. [image]

have changed `--dbpath` to `data/db` as comes by default, creating new folders, and tried to assign them to the path. and nothing worked

Comment: That error is a basic networking error. The server is trying to bind to a port, but another application is already running. It may be an instance of the server itself.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Looks like you tried to start mongod multiple times, that's not possible.

Comment: Aside from the other comments: this is off-topic here (not a programming question). And it has nothing to do with [tag:javascript] (I removed this tag, accordingly)